# PHP - Problemas para Procesar Descarga de Archivos

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Tengo un problema con un script que manda la descarga de archivos, algo extra~o sucede que no estaba pasando al parecer el archivo "se altera" cuando le paso la funcion de "file_get_contents()" en PHP:

```
<?php
$put_file= 'Nombre_del_Archivo.zip';
$put_url= '/mnt/data/archivo.zip';
$offset= 3600 * 24;

header( 'Expires: '. gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $offset). ' GMT' );
header( 'Last-Modified: '. gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time()). ' GMT' );
header( 'Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600' );
header( 'Vary: Accept-Encoding' );
header( 'Content-Type: application/zip' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $put_file. '"' );
echo file_get_contents($put_url);
?>
```

**Cabeceras del Response**

```
Expires: Tue, 06 Feb 2024 22:08:45 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 05 Feb 2024 22:08:45 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Nombre_del_Archivo.zip"
PK..... toda la data.....
```

Y el problema de todo este asunto es que los archivo ZIP se estan bajando tipo "da~ados", osea el mismo sistema de Windows no lee el ZIP, esto ya lo comprobé en otras maquinas (para descartar que fuera solo mio el problema).